# Diferencia entre CorrelationId y TraceId

Tags: java, log4j, quarkus

¡Hola comunidad! En mi trabajo implementé en Java con Quarkus un provider que retiene las request que entran a la api, se genera un uuid y se lo coloca dentro de librería log4j como un parámetro más del log por lo que se puede seguir la trazabilidad de la request pero si la request entrante tiene x-cotrelation-id como parámetro en el header lo toma. A este concepto lo conocía como CorrelationId pero al ver los logs ví que ya tenía el parámetro traceId.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre CorrelationId y TraceId?

Por lo que investigue son conceptos muy parecidos y no encuentro la diferencia

¡Muchas gracias!